# What indexing info is needed to quickly check if a node of a Directed Acyclic Graph is before, after, or parallel to another node?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

I'm trying to find a quick way to check the relative ordering of two nodes of a directed acyclic graph. A node can come before, come after, or be parallel to another node. Here is an example:

[image: DAG illustration: A->B, A->C, A->D, B->F, C->E, D->H, E->G, E->H, F->I, G->I, H->I, H->J, I->K, J->K]

Node H comes after A, C, D, and E, but is parallel to B, F, and G, and comes before I, J, and K.

I'd like to find a way of doing this kind of node comparison with minimal graph traversal, by building up an index (or several indices) as I construct the graph.  Ideally, every time I add a node or an edge, I'd only need to set its indices, and not update other values around it.  I'm not sure if it's possible, but it feels like it could be?

My initial approaches didn't go so well.  Here is an illustration of 4 steps of my initial thought process of trying to construct of a different graph:

[image: 1: A->B | (A=1;B=128). 2: A->C, C->B | (A=1;B;128;C=64). 3: A->C, A->D, C->B, D->B | (A=1;B=128;C=64;D=64). 4: A->C, A->D, C->E, D->B, E->B | (A=1;B=128;C=64;D=64,2;E=96).]

1. I assign a high value (128) as the index to the endpoint, B.
2. Splitting the edge in half, I assign the halfway value, 64, to C.  The comparison still holds between any two points.
3. I link A and B again in parallel.  It's also half, 64, and the comparisons are still valid: D is equal (parallel) to C.
4. I split the CB link, giving the new node E a value of 96. Now things get weird.  The comparison doesn't work anymore, since E(96) is greater than D(64), but needs to be parallel.  I try going back to step 3 and adding a second value 2 to D, to indicate the branch it is on.  Now, if I compare D to E, I first check if the branch value is equal (with a default branch value of 1).

After this the method breaks down.  What branch value do I give B?  What happens if I add an edge from D to E?  Perhaps I need to keep adding lots of branching values, but it seems like this approach could lead to each index growing to the size of the graph itself.  I'd like to keep it memory efficient if possible, although I could do some time/space tradeoffs and do some localized graph traversal, if it's worth it.

Does anyone know of a solution to this, or some search terms I could use to look into further?  Thanks!

EDIT: It looks like a topological ordering is what I'm looking for.  Although it won't tell me if two nodes are parallel, it might be sufficient for now.  My new question would be, how can I efficiently update the topological ordering data when adding new nodes and edges?

Comment: Why don't you do topological sort?

Comment: @haluk Oh that's a good search term, this is really helpful.  It looks like a topological ordering will let me check if something is before-or-parallel, or after-or-parallel, but not just parallel.  That might not be an issue, it may work for my needs.  I'll have to create an in-place update of the ordering each time I add a node, without running the whole toposort after every change.